# Probability of Coin Game

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we play the following game. We take turns tossing a fair coin, and whoever is the first to reach $2$ heads (not necessarily in a row) wins. You go first. Draws are not allowed, so for example, if you flip heads, then I flip heads, and then you flip heads again, you win (I don't get a chance to toss the coin again).
What is the probability that you will win the game? Enter your answer as a fraction, such as $\frac23$.

I'm not sure how to approach this. I understand the probability of getting a head on the first two tries is $\frac14$. I also understand that the first person who goes should have better odds.  Just not sure how to approach this with infinite turns until you get two heads.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If it is, tell us so we can mark it as so.

Comment: Yea it is a homework question

Answer (score 5):

At any point in the game when it's your go, you are at one of 4 situations:

A) You have thrown 1 head and your opponent has thrown 1 head.

B) You have thrown 1 head and your opponent has thrown 0 heads.

C) You have thrown 0 heads and your opponent has thrown 1 head.

D) You have thrown 0 head and your opponent has thrown 0 head

Then we have to think about how we get from one situation to another:

We write for simplicity 'P(X)' to mean 'the probability of winning the game given you are at situation X'.

P(A) = 0.5 + 0.25P(A) => P(A) = 2/3

P(B) = 0.5 + 0.25P(B) + 0.25P(A) => P(B) = 8/9

P(C) = 0.25P(A) + 0.25P(C) => P(C) = 2/9

P(D) = 0.25P(A) + 0.25P(B) + 0.25P(C) + 0.25P(D) => P(D) = 16/27

Comment: So those are the odds of winning the game with each situation, this makes much more sense. So to calculate the overall probability, would i add and divide by 4 (probably a dumb conclusion to come to). I figured P(D) would be the answer but it wasn't given I'm trying to determine probability at 0 heads by both.

Comment: At the start of the game you are at D, so P(D) is the probability that you win.

Answer (score 2):

The game has $10$ states that can be addressed in the form $(F,a,b)$,where $F\in\{A,B\}$ denotes the immediately foregoing player, $a$ denotes the number of heads obtained so far by $A$, and $b$ denotes the number of heads so far obtained by $B$. When $a=2$ or $b=2$ the game is over, and the value $\leq1$ of the other variable is irrelevant.

Denote by $p(F,a,b)$ the probability that $A$ ("I" in the question) wins when the game is in state $(P,a,b)$. Then $p(A,2,b)=1$ and $p(B,a,2)=0$, and our aim is to compute $p(B,0,0)$.

This setup furnishes $8$ more equations of the form
$$p(A,1,0)={1\over2}\bigl(p(B,1,0)+p(B,1,1)\bigr)$$
and similar. Solving the resulting system of equations gives
$${\mathbb P}\bigl({\rm I\ win}\bigr)=p(B,0,0)={16\over27}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

U - you , O - Opponent

1st Try: No body wins

2nd Try: You toss a head, you win with a probability of 1/4. (Because you could have thrown (HT,TH,TT)

2rd Try:  Your opponent throws the unwinning 2nd try with P(O') = 3/4

After 2nd try, P(U) = 1/4

3rd Try:

Number of winning counts out of unwinning 2nd Try = P(U) = 2/6 & P(O') = 3/4

At this moment, P(U) = $(1/4)+(3/4)^2*(2/6)$ meaning both of you failed to win in the second try and you win in the third try

3rd Try: Your opponent throws the unwinning No of heads = {HTT,THT,TTH,TTT} of {HTT,HTH,THT,THH,TTH,TTT} giving a probability of 4/6 Now the P(O')

4th Try: P(O').P(U)

Number of winning counts out of unwinning 3rd try = P(U) = 3/8

At this moment, P(U) = $(1/4)+(3/4)^2*(2/6)+(3/4)^2*(4/6)^2*(3/8)$ meaning both of you failed to win in the second try  and the third try and you win in the fourth try

Thus you get the series

$$P(U) = (1/4)+(3/4)^2*(2/6)+(3/4)^2*(4/6)^2*(3/8)+(3/4)^2*(4/6)^2*(5/8)^2*4/10+...$$

This reduces to  $$\sum_2^{\infty}\frac{n(n-1)}{2^{(2n-1)}}$$

Which when you evaluate gives you the answer 16/27 and concurs with answer of the other responder.  You can evaluate the series in wolfram alpha.  This is a simple way to make students think about games. Answer: goo.gl/eUj8O5

Thanks

Satish

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose that the person who starts tossing the coin wins the game in $(2k+1)^{th}$ toss. So each player has tossed $k$ times before the winning toss.
Winner has tossed $1$ Head and $k-1$ Tails in his k tosses. 
Loser may have tossed all Tails(Case 1) or $1$ Head + $k-1$ Tails.(Case 2)

Case 1. 
Probability of Winning = $k*(\frac{1}{2})^{2*k+1}$

Because there are $k$ ways to achieve one head and and $k-1$ tails(for winner) and only one way to achieve all tails(for loser) in $k$ tosses

Case 2.

Probability  of Winning  = $\frac{k*k}{2}*(\frac{1}{2})^{2*k+1}$

Similar to above case now the number of ways(arrangements of T,H etc is $\frac{k*k}{2}$

Total probability of winning in $(2k+1)^{th}$ toss is Case 1 + Case 2.

$P_{2*k+1}$ = $\frac{k*(k+1)}{2}*(\frac{1}{2})^{2*k+1}$

Now answer to your question is summation of $P_{2*k+1}$ from $k=1$ to $\infty$

Let $S$ = $\frac{1*2}{2^3}$ + $\frac{2*3}{2^5}$ + $\frac{3*4}{2^7}$ ..
This series is a simple Arithematico-Geometric Series which adds up to $\frac{16}{27}$